# Getting a token request error when used .search with spotipy

Tags: spotipy

I am currently trying to use the spotipy package to scrape artist information from Spotify. When I am trying to make a non-authorized request, I am getting a token error. Can someone help me out?

non-authorized request[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtWN3.png)
error [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtKCG.png)png

Comment: My guess is that you need to not make a non-authorized request.

Comment: Yep; see "Authorization": https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/search-item/

Comment: I am just confused because, unless Spotify updated their API, searches (I worked with this two days ago) it did not require Authorization

Comment: They did. https://twitter.com/SpotifyPlatform/status/865319073281912836

Comment: Thank you so much!